# Love2D clipping mask

Tags: lua, love2d

In love2D, I'm trying to emulate a reflection on the water in 2D. The problem is that the reflection can come off the water like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVzb4.jpg)

I've tried to use love.graphics.setScissor(), but it seems to effect all of the graphics on the screen.

Does anyone know how to stop the reflection coming off the water??

the code to create the reflection is as follows:

```
playerClone.Position=Vector2.new(player.entity.Position.x, (2*water.Position.y-player.entity.Position.y)-50)
playerClone.Rotation=-player.entity.Rotation
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with the draw order, if theshore draws after the water, with the reflection between, the reflection will be on top of the water but hidden behind the shore so the reflection will stop where the water meets the shore...? Not certain I understand your problem though as that screenshot is not very vivid ...

Comment: It did seem to be a problem with scissor not working with the camera system I was using. I ended up using stencil to get my wanted effect